# como evitar numeros repetidos en un array en c++

Tags: c++

Buenas estoy intentado crear un sistema que guarda los datos de los usuarios en un archivo. Estoy haciendo una validacion la cual es  "no debería  haber duplicación de  papeletas  en el array". Papeleta son un numero que identifica a los empleados en una empresa

Mi idea era crear el arreglo o vector. Iterarlo primero y verificar si existe o no. En caso de que exista lo guarde en el archivo y sino que no lo guarde. Hasta ahora no he encontrado una manera de evitar el duplicado de datos en c++, espero que me ayuden

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int opcion;
void Empleados();
void menu();


void menu(){

cout<<"Menu"<<endl;
cout<<"1)Empleados"<<endl;
cout<<"Elige una opcion: ";
cin>>opcion;

switch(opcion){

 case 1: 
   Empleado();
  break;
}

}

void Empleado(){

float papeletas[100] = {};
float num;
  
  
  ofstream archivo;
  
  archivo.open("empleado.txt",ios::app);

  
  
  char band = 'F';


for(int i=0;i<100;){

band = 'F';

cout<<"ingresa la papeleta "<<endl;
cin>>num;

for(j=0; j<sizeof(num); j++){

if(papeleta[j] == num){

cout<<" ya el dato existe en el sistema"<<endl;

}


else{

papeleta[i] = num;
i++;

}
  


}
}  

  archivo.close();
  
  }


int main(){

menu();
lectura();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ tiene una serie de utilidades que te pueden hacer la vida más sencilla en bastantes ocasiones.

Una de esas utilidades son los contenedores. La inmensa mayoría de los programas utilizan listas y colecciones de datos, así que parece buena idea que el estándar te provea de una serie de implementaciones básicas. El contenedor que te interesa a ti es `std::set`. Este contenedor es una colección de elementos que, entre otras cosas, **no admite duplicados**. Puedes almacenar ahí las cédulas para ayudarte a detectar los duplicados:

```
bool NuevaCedula(std::set<int> & cedulas, int cedula)
{
    // C++11
    bool added;
    std::tie(std::ignore, added) = cedulas.insert(cedula);

    // C++17
    auto [_, added] = cedulas.insert(cedula);
    //    ^ El primer valor no nos interesa
    //      "_" es un nombre de variable valido

    // C++03 y anteriores
    bool added;
    std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool> pair = cedulas.insert(cedula);
    added = pair.second;
    
    return added;
}


int[] lista_cedulas = { 123, 456, 456, 789, 123 };
std::set<int> cedulas_registradas;

for( int cedula : lista_cedulas )
{
    if (!NuevaCedula(cedulas, cedula))
    {
        std::cout << "La cedula " + cedula + " ya se encuentra registrada\n";
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, para que funcione correctamente lo primero que tienes que hacer es leer el archivo y registrar todas las cédulas. También, en caso de que el programa lo admita, deberás borrar las cédulas de los registros eliminados.

Comment: @JoséGabrielPuenteSalgueiro para eso estamos. Un saludo

Comment: @JoséGabrielPuenteSalgueiro Intenta que el programa tenga sentido, es decir, por ejemplo no uses algo antes de haberlo inicializado correctamente, intenta tabular correctamente el código, usa nombres de variables que signifiquen algo. Es un buen comienzo. Sobre dónde poner el código que de la respuesta ... eso ya es más bien subjetivo y complicado de responder sin ver el estado del código. Con práctica irás viendo dónde poner cada parte con más facilidad